# Split multiple choice answers (MS Forms) to separate columns in Excel with Power Automate

Tags: excel, power-automate, ms-forms

It seems that this has already been explained but I'm pretty new to Power Automate and couldn't understand the answers...

I created a form with single choice and multiple choices questions and would like Power Automate to automatically split the answers into different columns.

[image]

So far I have been able to break the string but Power Automate add rows instead of columns and I'm stuck!

[image]

Any tips please?

Many thanks,
Mel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXwuw.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example of the forms response, ie the data from **Get response details**. It appears as though you’re looping over each individual answer to each question, hence why it’s adding multiple rows to Excel.

Comment: Hi Skin
1st multiple choice questions would be 
"Please select all disciplinary expertise from the following
- Natural Science/Knowledge 
- Social Science/Knowledge 
- Interdisciplinary approaches 
- Political Science/Political Economy Analysis
- Other (specify)"
2nd multiple question would be 
"Please select all your geographic experience from the following
- Africa 
- Asia-Pacific 
- Latin America - Caribbean 
- Other ODA-eligible countries - please specify"
Best

Comment: No, sorry, I need the JSON.

Comment: Hi Skin, apology for the late reply but the form and the spreadsheet have been deleted...